# Traer y agrupar celdas desde MySQL en PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json

Tengo una base de datos que se asemeja a la siguiente estructura:

| CODIGO | TITULO | CANTIDAD |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | OBJETO1 | 5 |
| 02 | OBJETO1 | 150 |
| 03 | OBJETO1 | 2 |
| 04 | OBJETO2 | 6 |

Estos datos provienen de un archivo de Excel el cual simplemente pasé a SQL, y no puedo modificar los campos. Necesito traer esta información por PHP y formatearla en JSON para desplegarla en un grafico, de manera que aquellos valores que compartan el mismo 'TITULO' se sumen, es decir, en el ejemplo, que OBJETO1 tenga una cantidad de 157. Estuve intentando con el siguiente código, sin exito:

```
    <?php 
    include 'conexion2.php';
    $sql = "SELECT titulo, cantidad FROM stock_disp GROUP BY titulo ORDER BY cantidad DESC";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion2, $sql);
    $arreglo_registros = array();

    while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){ 
        $registro['titulo'] = $data['titulo'];
        $registro['cantidad'] = $data['cantidad'];
    
        $arreglo_registros[] = $registro;
    }

    echo json_encode($arreglo_registros);
    ?>
```

Alguna idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esto se puede resolver directamente desde la consulta MySQL con [SUM](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sum/).

```
SELECT titulo, SUM(cantidad) as cantidad 
FROM stock_disp 
GROUP BY titulo ORDER BY cantidad DESC;
```

Lo que devuelve:

```
titulo  | cantidad
--------+---------
OBJETO1   157
OBJETO2   6
```

Answer (score 2):

La respuesta de @aeportugal es la correcta y la más optimizado.
Ahora te voy a dejar una alternativa si lo deseas hacer como lo estabas haciendo con **PHP**.

Podrías pasarle como clave el título, así podrás saber si el titulo existe o no.

`$registro[ ($data['titulo']) ]`

Ahora podemos simplemente añadir la cantidad de la siguiente forma:

`$registro[ ($data['titulo']) ] = $data['cantidad'];`

**Ejemplo completo:**

```
// Reseteo
$arreglo_registros = $registro = [];

// Obtener datos
while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) { 

    // Comprobamos si la clave existe
    if (array_key_exists($data['titulo'], $registro)) :
                   
      // Actualizamos la suma
      $registro[ ($data['titulo']) ] += $data['cantidad'];

    // La clave no existe, iniciamos primera cantidad
    else :
      $registro[ ($data['titulo']) ] = $data['cantidad'];
    endif;        

    //$arreglo_registros[] = $registro;
}
// Salida
echo '<pre>';
print_r($registro);
echo '</pre>';
```

Salida:

```
Array
(
    [OBJETO1] =>  157
    [OBJETO2] =>  6
)
```